# Display Machine name on a label on master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a label on master page on which I want to display the machine name. I am using this but its not working:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" style="font-size: large; color: #009999" runat="server" Text= 'MACHINE NAME IS <%# Environment.MachineName %>' ></asp:Label>
```

How to correct it?

Comment: Why you not use Page_Load and set Label1.Text = Environment.MachineName?

Comment: @RoBYCoNTe I have to do this on master page only.

Comment: Are you looking for the machine name of the server or of the client viewing the site?

Comment: @James machine name of the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%#` is a [data binding expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) and will only work where data binding is supported. There is no data source for your entire page, therefore the data binding fails.

You could try just emitting plain old HTML:

```
<span><%= Environment.MachineName %></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using **data binding** tags rather than just standard HTML output tags, change your `Text` value to be:

```
...Text='MACHINE NAME IS <%= Environment.MachineName %>'...
```